# Is proof for $\int_0^{x^2} e^{t^2} dt \ge x \sin x$ for $x \ge 0$ correct?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives, proof-verification, definite-integrals

$$F(x)= \int_0^{x^2} e^{t^2} dt$$

show: for each $x \ge 0: \space$ $F(x) \ge x \sin x$

I know the solution that define $G(x)=F(x)-x \sin x \space$ and showing it increasing using derivatives.

But is that solution correct:

There exists $c \ge 0$ such that:

$F(x)= \int_0^{x^2} e^{t^2} dt = e^{c^2} x^2 = x \cdot xe^{c^2} \ge x \cdot x \ge x \sin x$

because $e^{c^2} \ge 1$ and $x \ge \sin x$ (when $x \ge 0$).

?

Comment: It is okay ${}$

Comment: Looks ok to me. You could also observe  that  $e^{t^2}\geq 1\to \int_0^{x^2} e^{t^2}dt\geq \int_0^{x^2}1 dx=x^2\geq x \sin x$ for all $x$.